# richfaces a4j:ajax action never executes

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have this

```
<h:inputText id="betOpTxt" validatorMessage="cannot be less than 10"
                           style="text-align: right; width: 100%" 
                           value="#{amtAction.amount}">
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="10" />
    <rich:validator />                  
    <a4j:ajax execute="@this" action="#{amtAction.performCalculation}" event="blur" />
</h:inputText>
```

The action of `a4j:ajax` never executes. I wonder what is wrong
Please help (i within the `richfaces` mobile implementation)

Answer (score 11):

This is because there is no such attribute called *"action"* in a4j:ajax. Use *"listener"* attribute instead.